# SH para recorrer carpeta y copiar archivos

Tags: linux, script

Sé que es una chorradilla pero para alguien de windows se complica la vida
Necesito crear un script para linux que recorra una carpeta en la que se irán metiendo archivos de vez en cuando (sin horas específicas porque lo meterán otros usuarios), los cuales no sé cómo se llamarán pero si se que serán .wav y necesito copiarlos a otro directorio
Me podéis echar una mano? Muchas gracias
Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy la idea que se me ocurre:

- Usa cron para programar la tarea periodicamente
- usa `find -r <DIRECTORIO> -iregex '.*.wav'` para sacar la lista de archivos existente
- Si necesitas copiar, deberás crear un archivo para saber cuáles ya han sido copiados y comparar para copiar solo los nuevos. O puedes sobreescribirlos si no importa.
- Teniendo la lista de archivos, puedes iterar usando un `for` y concatenando el archivo al comando `gpg`. Ejemplo:

`for ARCHIVO in $lista
    do
        gpg -e -r userID $ARCHIVO
        ...
        OTROS COMANDOS
        ...
    done`

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Vale, primera parte cumplida pero me falta algo importante que no especifiqué pensando que podría trabajar cada archivo por separado.
Antes de mover el archivo lo tengo que encriptar con gpg, entiendo que la  línea a agregar sería: 
gpg -e -r userID <nombre_del_archivo_que_queremos_encriptar> 
pero el problema que tengo es que no sé como poder pasar por parámetro el nombre de un archivo que desconozco.
En conclusión, meten los archivos, recorro las carpetas para encontrarlos, los encripto y los copio o corto
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, he editado la respuesta. Puedes almacenar el listado de archivos en una variable e iterar sobre cada elemento para aplicar el procesamiento que requieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Conseguido

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el comando cp de linux...

Crea un archivo con el editor de texto de tu preferencia y pega lo siguiente y modifica por tu ruta de origen y la ruta en la que se guardaran.

```
#! /bin/bash

cp -f /tu/ruta/de/origen/*.wav /tu/ruta/de/destino
```

Y lo guardas como un archivo **.sh** y lo ejecutas desde tu terminal como **./nombre_script.sh** o  **sh nombre_script.sh**

Comment: Gracias, 
Añado un poco más de dificultad en la respuesta anterior
" Vale, primera parte cumplida pero me falta algo importante que no especifiqué pensando que podría trabajar cada archivo por separado. Antes de mover el archivo lo tengo que encriptar con gpg, entiendo que la línea a agregar sería: gpg -e -r userID <nombre_del_archivo_que_queremos_encriptar> pero el problema que tengo es que no sé como poder pasar por parámetro el nombre de un archivo que desconozco. En conclusión, meten los archivos, recorro las carpetas para encontrarlos, los encripto y los copio o corto Muchas gracias"

Answer (score -1):

es ta simple como usar el comando rsync:

```
rsync -avz /origen/ /destino/
```

esto sincronizara los archivos de ambas carpetas en caso de que exista solo compara los archivos que an sido modificados

tambien podrias hacerlo mediante el comando diff:

```
diff -qr ./origen ./destino/ | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 -J% cp % ./destino/
```

Comment: Gracias Bryco,
He obviado no pensando en lo que me podías proponer una parte. Lo he puesto en los comentarios anteriores